# Receiving unexpected readings from a SDM230 Modbus RTU Meter

Tags: raspberry-pi, modbus, minimalmodbus

I am attempting to retrieve data from a SDM230 Modbus RTU Meter using a raspberry Pi running minimalmodbus (python3).

The response every time is:

```
Response from instrument: 01 03 02 00 00 B8 44 (7 bytes)
```

or if I request with read_float() four bytes:

```
Response from instrument: 01 03 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 95 D7 (13 bytes)
```

and the voltage value (register starts at 0) is 0.0.

*Update 2023-05-23 22:16*
I've found [a posting](https://community.openenergymonitor.org/t/read-the-sdm220-modbus-with-the-minimalmodbus-python-module/4819) for SDM220 Modbus Meter. The procedures/methods there are very similar to mine. This meter is a predecessor model of mine.
I can therefore not completely rule out that my measuring device has a quirk.

I have already contacted the supplier (B+G) and will update the question if I receive a response.

Comment: You might get ore responses at [raspberrypi.se].

Comment: It you are getting a valid response (and you are) then the issue is with your request or the SDM230 (and the fact you are using a Pi is irrelevant). It looks like you are requesting holding registers (function code `03`) when the info you want is in input registers (function code `04`). The Modicon numbering scheme used in the documentation can be a bit confusing...

Comment: It would be much easier if you'd provided the code you wrote to interface to the SDM220 and if you could show your out-going (TX) commands as well, not just the RX.